# Interval Tree implementation taking a lot of filespace space after serialization

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, serialization, tree

I have a text file which contains IPv6 ranges and which ISP a range belongs to (ranges **do not overlaps**). Some sample (fake) rows are the following:

```
2010:258:0:0:0:0:0:0;2010:258:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff;ISP_1;
2010:260:0:0:0:0:0:0;2010:260:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff;ISP_2;
2010:268:0:0:0:0:0:0;2010:268:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff;ISP_3;
```

I have taken this text file and created an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) out of it, so that I can quickly lookup which ISP a specific IP belongs to. Every node in the Interval tree has the following structure:

```
public class Node implements Serializable {
    Range nodeRange;

    IntervalTreeNode left;
    IntervalTreeNode right;

    UnsignedLong128 centerValue;

}
```

Here is `Range`:

```
public abstract class Range implements Comparable<Range>, Serializable {

    UnsignedLong128 start;
    UnsignedLong128 end;
    boolean sortAccordingToStart;
}
```

where `UnsignedLong128` is a custom Long class I've written which is 128 bits long:

```
public class UnsignedLong128 implements Comparable<UnsignedLong128>, Serializable {

    Long major;
    Long minor;
}
```

Problem is, if I serialize and write the tree to a file, **the size of that file is MUCH larger than the original text file**. Here's an example: I had a text file containing 19860 range rows and that text file was 1.7 MB in size. When I created the Interval Tree based on it and wrote that tree to file (through Java's serialization), **the size of the resulting file was 15.7 MB**, even though it's storing the same information. Yes, the tree holds upto twice the amount of nodes than the number of rows in the text file (the tree I'm generating is balanced), this still doesn't justify the file size increasing so much.

So what's causing this file size to grow, and how can I trim it down ?

Comment: If you don't need to stick with serialization, you could also create a `readFile` and a `toFile` method to store the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Java serialization will have a lot of overhead, which you can probably see if you look at the file with a text editor.

Since the ranges do not overlap, you could just keep the data in sorted order (comparing two ranges comparing their start points or end points) and use binary search to find a match. Then you just have to serialize an array of structures. You might find there is less overhead with Java serialization where you have one large array, or three large arrays, holding start points, end points, and ISP ids, or you could read and write the data yourself.

You could also investigate readResolve() and writeReplace()

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `Externalizable` which allows you to do customize the serialization while staying withing the `Serializable` framework. It's rather simple, you need something like one line per field and per direction. `Serializable` has some overhead as every field may contain `null` or an instance of a subclass of its type, but you usually know that it can't happen.

I'm not sure, but I guess that `Serializable` uses UTF-16 by default, which is fast and simple as that's about what Java internally does (or did, as Java 9 can do better), but it wastes a factor of two for your pure ASCII (using UTF-8 is fine). It looks like you replaced strings by numbers, so it mayn't help.

Your `UnsignedLong128` is wasteful also in memory. Replace `Long` by `long`. No idea, how much it helps with the serialized data size, but you save a lot of RAM (and gain some speed).